# Экспорт данных из TinyDB в csv

Tags: java, android, csv, android-shared-preferences

В моем приложении я использую библиотеку TinyDB для сохранения\восстановления данных из SharedPreferences. Например:

```
TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(this);
counter = tinyDB.getInt("USERCOUNTERNEWS");
```

Возможно ли экспортировать имеющиеся данные в csv?